# Fastboot flash boot (FAILED)

Tags: adb, twrp, fastboot, linux

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and when trying to boot into, or flash, the TWRP recovery bootimage image I compiled.

I have no additional information on why I got this error.
Just flashing twrp bootimage on moto g(40) fusion.
Error I received on executing `fastboot boot boot.img`:

```
$    downloading 'boot.img'...
$    FAILED (command write failed (Success))
$    finished. total time: 0.000s
```

Comment: the reason is you compiled yourself

Comment: Do you know on which partition you have to flash boot_a or boot_b

Comment: afaik in active slot

Comment: on partition boot_a

Comment: Should I use fastboot set_active a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was resolved on **using different usb slot** to connect my device via usb cable.
I still have no idea on why I got this error but it was resolved.
Maybe **using a different usb cable** might also solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/fastboot-problem-on-usb-3-0-ports.3859995/ also talks about this problem, although it might be a different case.

In their case, it was a Poco F1 phone, a computer with a AMD CPU, and a **USB 3.0 port**. Downgrading to USB 2.0 fixed the problem

The thread also offered a way to fix it on Windows by running these commands as administrator. I'm not sure what they do, but they seem to force USB 2.0

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\18D1D00D0100" /v "osvc" /t REG_BINARY /d "0000" /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\18D1D00D0100" /v "SkipContainerIdQuery" /t REG_BINARY /d "01000000" /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\18D1D00D0100" /v "SkipBOSDescriptorQuery" /t REG_BINARY /d "01000000" /f
```